# Is there a way to disable the `takeScreenshot()` action when an OpenTest test fails?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, opentest

Sometimes it's useful to do something like loop an `AssertElementNotVisible()` until the element in question is visible. However, the `takeScreenshot()` event is quite slow, and each time the test fails until it succeeds, it will take a screenshot. This slows everything down. Is there a way to disable the screenshot taken on test failure?